# Sending an array of js objects to apex controller in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to pass an array of js objects to apex controller. Can anyone please help me on this? I guess in the apex side I need to use map. Here is the code I am using. But at the apex side I am getting null.

js:

```
0:
id: "a1S25000001pAWaEAM"
comment: "Natu"
__proto__: Object
1:
id: "a1S25000001pFEdEAM"
comment: "satisu"
__proto__: Object
2:
id: "a1S25000001pKoEEAU"
comment: "jay"
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ResponseData updateOtherContactsWithComments(Map<String, String> otherContacts){
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        system.debug('param: '+ otherContacts);
        return responseData;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a class, it'd be a list of maps:

```
public static ResponseData updateOtherContactsWithComments(
    List<Map<String, String>> otherContacts
){
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I prefer to send it as a JSON string to the apex function and then deserialize into a class that I can then manipulate.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ResponseData updateOtherContactsWithComments(String otherContactsString) {
    List<OtherContact> otherContacts = (List<OtherContact>) JSON.deserialize(otherContactsString, List<OtherContact>.class);
    // TO DO
}

//Properties should reflect the objects in the array for the deserialization to work
private class OtherContact{
    Id id {get; set;}
    String comment {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: If all you are passing is a list of contacts you don't need to create the "OtherContact" class and should rather just use the actual Contact sObject as the class you deserialize the data into.